# Applying gradient texture to deformed volume based on Z coordinate

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shaders, volumetrics, displacement

I'm trying to apply a fog to my grass plane, which is deformed in multiple ways (plane is subdivied + waved by hand + 2x modifier: displace.
The fog is supposed to be dense at the bottom and disappear with height, based on the gradient.
But the gradient is applied to the whole object, not the local Z coordinates of the volume.
Fog is generated with Volume Shatter.

I know the description is complicated, so, IMAGES!
What I have is rendered, what I want is with those arrows.
[image]

[1]What I 'want' presented with a surface shader:
[image]
[2]What I have:
[image]
[3]This is how it looks in volume shatter:
[image]

So:
I want the effect from [1] to apply to volume.
Please help. I'm Struggling with this for days...

I hope I didn't use wrong tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guy from blender IRC support channel (#blender on freenode) found the answer, so, as follows!

There are **TWO** methods. First one is raytracing:
[image: first method]
It's really slow, and OSL depending. And casuses crashes, apperently ;)

Second method, **much faster** (bueno!) uses height maps instead of gradient texture.
[image: height map method]
[image: nodes]
[image: height map]

Also, @JA12 simplified it even more, look at the nodes:
[image]

You can study it with the attached .blend file.
It's amazingly simple.
[.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48641) my mirror: [mirror](http://sf.comuf.com/blender/heightmap_test.blend)